# What is a generic term for name/identifier? (as opposed to label)

Tags: documentation, naming, coding-standards

I need to refer to a number of *things* that have both an identifier value (used in code and configuration), and a human-readable label. These things include:

- database columns
- dropdown items
- subapplications
- objects stored in a dictionary

I want two unambiguous terms. One to refer to the identifier/value/key. One to refer to the label.

As you can see, I'm pretty settled on the latter :) For the former, *identifier* seems best (not everything is strictly a *key*, and *value* and *name* could refer to the label; although, *identifier* usually refers only to a variable name), but I would prefer to follow an established practice if there is one.

Is there an established term for this? (Please provide a source.) If not, are there any examples of a choice from a significant source (Java APIs, MSDN, a big FLOSS project)?

*(I wasn't sure if this should be posted here or to [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/). I thought this was the more appropriate expert audience. Happy to migrate if not.)*

Comment: Are there three things here?  The name of the column the data comes from (for example) the label you use on the user interface and the data itself?

Comment: @JonStrayer yes (potentially) and they each have an identifier and a label

Answer (score 3):

Such things are usually called "**opaque identifiers**".  The have no intrinsic meaning (*e.g.*, they're not the next monotonically-increasing integer value of some database column), you cannot expect to perform any operation on them other than mapping to the label and the object itself (*e.g.*, you can't concatenate it with something to get something else), *etc.*.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with `id`, both as the term most commonly used (in my experience) and as a personal preference.

Answer (score 2):

I would favour `Identity` over `Identifier`. The identifier is the value of the identity, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

A commonly used term is *Name-value pair*. The *name* part being the identifier and *value* being what you refer to as label.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I would suggest it is a key, value pair.  "Key" is the common term when describing the unique identifiers in [associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) such as in Java's Map class, and is also what can uniquely identify a row in a database relation.

"Key" is also the familiar term when discussing decoding thins--when you see this, it means that...

The problem you can run into with "name" is that it implies something meaningful--especially when you are describing people or other things that explicitly have "names" (but which aren't necessarily useful as unique identifiers or keys).